# py.test and mpi test cases

Tags: mpi, pytest

I just created a package with sequential test cases running with [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/). But, now, I would like to run the same test cases in a distributed MPI context.

For example to run a test case on 4 processors :

```
$> mpirun -np 4 python test1.py
```

So, I would like to known if it is possible to do so with py.test ? and How ?

Comment: I don't know about MPI, but are you aware of [pytest-xdist](https://pytest.org/latest/xdist.html)?

Comment: `mpiexec -n 5 py.test test/` should do it as per https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html. If not, please provide an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Please use pytest-mpi to run any pytest test cases in parallel.

For example: `mpirun -n 2 python -m pytest test.py --only-mpi`

The test.py should have the markers to distinguish the tests to run sequentially or parallelly.

For more details follow the link [pytest-mpi](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mpi/).